# d3.js - d3.select("#id).remove() or .attr("class", "hidden") not working

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to remove or even set the class of a d3 svg element in my javascript however it doesn't seem to get applied.

The d3 element is part of a group  and if I set the id to a single word e.g. "region" it will delete/modify however I want but to the whole group.

I assign the id of all the elements with their specific names when I append them.

However, as the title suggests the d3.select is not allowing me to modify the existing element.

Here is an image of the structure in chrome element view.

[image: element view]

Example code of how the paths are constructed and how I'm trying to manipulate them.

```
// Construction
features.selectAll()
            .data(json.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", function (e) {
                return "region " + e.properties.Name + " feature";
            })
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("id", function(e) {
                return "region " + e.properties.Name + " feature";
            })
            .on("click", function (d) {
                qualifyType(d);
            });

// Manipulation
d3.select("#region South East feature").attr("class", "hidden");
d3.select("#region " + feature.properties.Name + " feature").remove();
```

I've tried a few other variations too such as d3.selectAll and what not but no joy.

Comment: Can you post example code that reproduces the problem please?

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me, I've updated the question to reflect your request. Hopefully it provides the context you're after, I'm doing this in an angular-js directive. I doubt you'd want to see the whole directive :)

Comment: Looks like your selector is wrong. Class names should be prefixed with a dot, so selecting element with ID `region` and classes `South East feature` would be `d3.select("#region .South .East .feature")`.

Comment: Okay, problem spotted. So in the construction if I don't assign the id as region South East feature and only do that in the class (which is how I was originally doing it in a previous version and makes sense to do) and have the class as "South East feature" for example. I can do, as you suggest - d3.select("#region.South.East.feature").remove(); and that works. The issue I was having is, I was really close but you can't have spaces. You can't do exagtly what you wrote "#region .South .E".. You have to remove the spaces. Again, thanks for your help, please put this as an answer so I can reward.

Comment: Ah, well spotted about the spaces. Will add as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D3 uses CSS selectors for selecting elements, and in those class names have to be prefixed by dots. So selecting the element with ID `region` and classes `South East feature` would look like this:

```
d3.select("#region.South.East.feature")
```

Comment: Will this work? I think the id actually has spaces in it like ```id="region South East feature"```. That is, 'South', 'East', and 'feature' are not classes but part of the id. I don't think spaces in ids are legal, which is probably the issue. [Edit: Whoops, didn't see that this is in the context of a comment above and not the original question. Another option would be to remove the spaces from the ID and use the original approach.]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html -- spaces are not allowed.